# How to ignore or remove first row from database (Cucumber/java)

Tags: java, cucumber

I have a datatable in my cucumber feature file and I want to output the data from the datatable as a list with commas separate in between. Now I have managed to do tis with the code below:

```
 String quoteIds = dataTable.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("\",\"", "\"", "\""));
```

However my problem is that it includes the first row which is the header. I know I can remove the header manually from the datatable but I want to know if there is a way to ignore the first row so it is not included in the list?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`skip(1)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#skip-long-) on the stream to discard the first element.

```
dataTable.stream().skip(1).collect(Collectors.joining("\",\"", "\"", "\""));
```